# missing a using directive or an assembly reference in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

updated to visual studio from 2012 to visual studio 2013. In one of the projects, system.web.mvc of version 5.2.2.0 does not recognize html helpers, models and razor syntax. when i change the version to 5.0.0.0 in the web config file, it does recognize the razor and the html helpers. what can be the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the assembly in Solution Explorer and select `Properties`.  Make sure the version in your web.config matches the value of the `Version` property.